# What is Diskio_io_time in AWS and how can i calculate the maximum limit of it?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, cloudwatch-alarms

I am little bit confused with this term diskio_io_time. From the AWS documentation i can see it is "The amount of time that the disk has had I/O requests queued" but i want to set an alarm in cloud watch for this metrics. How can i find out the maximum threshold limit of it?